# Configure Debezium to connect to given mySQL instance

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

Let's say, I would be getting multiple MySQL Instances and have to stream real time data. So for this, I have started few services on Docker Container by using the below Listed Commands which connects me to sample inventory database, and when I execute any DML commands in MySQL command Line Client, able to monitor those data changes.

But What are the changes required or the Equivalent Commands to connect to Actual MySQL Database and stream the same in watcher Window.

```
docker run -it --rm --name zookeeper -p 2181:2181 -p 2888:2888 -p 3888:3888 debezium/zookeeper:1.1

docker run -it --rm --name kafka -p 9092:9092 --link zookeeper:zookeeper debezium/kafka:1.1

docker run -it --rm --name mysql -p 3308:3308 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=debezium -e MYSQL_USER=mysqluser -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=mysqlpw debezium/example-mysql:1.1

docker run -it --rm --name mysqlterm --link mysql --rm mysql:5.7 sh -c "exec mysql -h"$MYSQL_PORT_3306_TCP_ADDR" -P"$MYSQL_PORT_3306_TCP_PORT" -uroot -p"debezium""

docker run -it --rm --name connect -p 8083:8083 -e GROUP_ID=1 -e CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC=my_connect_configs -e OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC=my_connect_offsets -e STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC=my_connect_statuses --link zookeeper:zookeeper --link kafka:kafka --link mysql:mysql debezium/connect:1.1

curl -i -X POST -H "Accept:application/json" -H "Content-Type:application/json" localhost:8083/connectors/ -d "{ \"name\": \"inventory-connector\", \"config\": { \"connector.class\": \"io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector\", \"tasks.max\": \"1\", \"database.hostname\": \"mysql\", \"database.port\": \"3306\", \"database.user\": \"debezium\", \"database.password\": \"dbz\", \"database.server.id\": \"184054\", \"database.server.name\": \"dbserver1\", \"database.whitelist\": \"inventory\", \"database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers\": \"kafka:9092\", \"database.history.kafka.topic\": \"dbhistory.inventory\" } }"

docker run -it --rm --name watcher --link zookeeper:zookeeper --link kafka:kafka debezium/kafka:1.1 watch-topic -a -k dbserver1.inventory.customers
```

Let's presume MySQL connection details as below:

```
Host address of MySQL : XXX.XXX.X.XXX
Databse/Schema : YYYYY
Username : ZZZZZ
Password : PPPPP
port : 3306
```

Any leads/Explanation would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This question has nothing to do with programming, therefore it is off topic here on SO. Dba or serverfault sister dites of SO offer help in such admin type questions.

Answer (score 1):

When you configure your connector with this

```
curl -i -X POST -H "Accept:application/json" -H "Content-Type:application/json" localhost:8083/connectors/ -d "{ \"name\": \"inventory-connector\", \"config\": { \"connector.class\": \"io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector\", \"tasks.max\": \"1\", \"database.hostname\": \"mysql\", \"database.port\": \"3306\", \"database.user\": \"debezium\", \"database.password\": \"dbz\", \"database.server.id\": \"184054\", \"database.server.name\": \"dbserver1\", \"database.whitelist\": \"inventory\", \"database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers\": \"kafka:9092\", \"database.history.kafka.topic\": \"dbhistory.inventory\" } }"
```

You amend it to include the details of your actual source database, e.g.

```
curl -i -X PUT -H  "Content-Type:application/json" \
    http://localhost:8083/connectors/source-mysql-01/config \
    -d '{
    "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "database.hostname": "XXX.XXX.X.XXX",
    "database.port": "3306",
    "database.user": "ZZZZZ",
    "database.password": "PPPPP",
    "database.server.id": "184054",
    "database.server.name": "dbserver1",
    "database.whitelist": "YYYYY",
    "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "kafka:9092",
    "database.history.kafka.topic": "dbhistory.YYYYY"
}'
```

Note that I've also changed to a `PUT` instead of a `POST` because it means you can re-run the command to amend an existing connector of the same name (and create it if it doesn't exist).

Comment: 1. Will rest of the commands remains same to monitor Local MySQL database ?             2. Any Settings required from Database side to capture CDC ?  As i'm able to start all the services but when i execute any of insert/update/delete SQL commands, Not able to see the response in the watcher window.

Comment: PUT says: HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
Date: Wed, 28 Apr 2021 20:16:47 GMT
Content-Length: 58
Server: Jetty(9.4.33.v20201020)

{"error_code":405,"message":"HTTP 405 Method Not Allowed"}

Comment: @cloudsurfin please post a new question with full details

Comment: I don't need to bug you with a whole new one. I'm just saying, when I use your exact code with PUT instead of POST I get a 405 back from the Kafka Connector (Debezium Mysql 1.5). When I replace it with POST this works great. Still learning kafka though so could be related.....

Comment: It's how StackOverflow works - new problem, post a new question :) That way distinct issues are solved directly, and things don't get confused or muddied by overlapping questions.

Comment: What is the difference between database.server.name, database.hostname and database.include.list? For example: my hostname is ec2-xxx.compute.amazonaws.com, the database is cooldb with all my tables inside, then what is the server.name? is there a default value for mysql?

Comment: @LuisEstrada please post a new question. You might also find the [Debezium gitter](https://gitter.im/debezium/user) a useful resource.

Comment: @RobinMoffatt here is new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71450836/difference-between-database-server-name-and-database-hostname-in-kafka-debezium