# How to get database.server.name for Kafka Debezium MySQL connector?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

**EDITING** the question:

Trying to configure a debezium MySQL Kafka connector, taking as example

https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/stable/connectors/mysql.html#mysql-example-configuration

I have:

- hostname: "ec2-xxx.compute.amazonaws.com"
- database: mycooldb (with all my tables inside)

Then I set the following properties like:

```
"database.hostname": "ec2-xxx.compute.amazonaws.com"
"database.include.list": "mycooldb"
```

And debezium has another property called "`database.server.name`". How can I find the server name value in MySql server?

A server can have multiple database, then in `database.include.list` I can include a list of databases.

`database.hostname` is the for the hostname or the ip.

I'm not sure about what's `database.server.name` and ***how to get the value from MySQL server?***. In the scenario if I want to include multiple datbases in database.include.list, then what's the value for atabase.server.name?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> *What is the difference between `database.server.name` and `database.hostname`*

Per the [docs](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/stable/connectors/mysql.html#mysql-connector-properties):

> - `database.hostname`: **IP address or host name of the MySQL database server**
> - `database.server.name`: **Logical name that identifies and provides a namespace for the particular MySQL database server**/cluster in which Debezium is capturing changes. The logical name should be unique across all other connectors, since it is used as a prefix for all Kafka topic names that receive events emitted by this connector. Only alphanumeric characters, hyphens, dots and underscores must be used in the database server logical name.

So `database.hostname` must be the host/IP of where the database can be found. `database.server.name` could be `fred` or `foobar` or `sales` or `anythingelse`. It's just a logical name for that database, and is used (as described above) in the Kafka topic.

Without `database.server.name` you'd have the potential problem ingesting a table called `foo` from two different databases using two different Debezium connectors and both trying to store it in a Kafka topic called `foo`. Hence the comment in the docs that `database.server.name` "…*provides a namespace*"

---

*Edit*: In regards to your comments, my answer is still accurate. The docs [detail topic naming](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/stable/connectors/mysql.html#mysql-topic-names), specifically the fact that the MySQL database name is used in part of the topic as is the `database.server.name`. If you connect to the same MySQL host (let's say we call it `database.server.name=fred`), and pull data from two databases on it called `sales` and `warehouse`, and each has a table called `audit`, you'd have two resulting Kafka topics:

- `fred.sales.audit`
- `fred.warehouse.audit`

Comment: Thanks Robin, I have edited the question because in the scenario if you want to include multiple database then you have to use database.include.list and it is not exclusive to database.server.name (single value). Then database.server.name is not for a database as you metion.

Comment: if you check the [examples](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/stable/connectors/mysql.html#mysql-connector-properties), the server name is : "dbserver1", and the database is "inventory". So you answer fred or foobar or sales or anythingelse are databases

Comment: I've elaborated on my answer to address your comments